# Could someone help me with "runas" command?

Tags: command-line

i am trying to insert text after opening  a command prompt.exe. i am trying this with this code 
`start runas /user:Administrator cmd.exe` except i cant use `/c` after the code for some reason. could someone tell me if there is a solution. please help me.

btw wrote this in a batch file

Answer (score 0):

put the invocation and arguments for cmd.exe in double quotes:

```
runas /user:Administrator "cmd.exe /c tracert www.google.com"
```

if you need double quotes inside the command string, use \ to escape them:

```
runas /user:Administrator "notepad \"my file.txt\""
```

Comment: I dont want the command or comment in cmd.exe. i want it to be inserted where you need to type in the password for admin cmd

Comment: then why would you want to use /c?